# First call of setSelected on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've got a general question which bothering me every time I'm designing a UITableView.

I want to select/deselect the cell according to a certain parameter. 
However, setselected method is being called before I initialise the object and then it can't really indicates it's status. 
Is there any way to call this method just upon click?
Or maybe I just need to do everything manually. Namely, design all the cell at first and then assign the UITableViewCell to response to my selector.

moreover, is there any way to make the entire cells selected as default?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either do it by code

```
select: [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];

deselect: [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

or maybe what you are looking for is having an external parameter that will indicates the real status of the cell

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is what you want, but you can always select and deselect a UITableViewCell with the following methods:

select:
`[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];`

deselect:
`[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`

you can make a cell selected by either selecting it in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or by selecting them in the `viewWillAppear` method of the UITableViewController

Comment: it's not what I was looking for but great tip anyway.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. thank you, got an idea how to design it myself...
Kind of customised setSelected.

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *) aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self)
    {
     self.highlighted = FALSE;
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tableCellClicked)];
     tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
     tapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
     [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tableCellClicked
{
        BetCellModeIndex cellMode = [self returnCellModeEnum ];
        switch (cellMode) {
            case Selected:
                cell.mode = notSelected;
                [self setSelectedStyle:  NotSelected];
                break;
            case NotSelected:
                cell.mode = selected;
                [self setSelectedStyle:  Selected];
                break;
            default:
                //TODO: HANDLE THE OTHER CASES
                break;
        }
     }
}

-(void) setSelectedStyle : (BetCellModeIndex) betCellModeIndex
{
switch (cellMode) {
    case Selected:
        self.backgroundColor =  [UIColor greenColor];
        break;
    case NotSelected:
        self.backgroundColor =  [UIColor redColor];
        break;
    default:
        //TODO: HANDLE THE OTHER CASES
        break;

     }
 }
```